# One to zero-or-one with HasForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-entity-framework

I have two models:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; } // optional
}

public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person {get; set; } // required
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        Property(e=>e.PersonId) // I need this property mapped
            .HasColumnName("person_id")
            .HasColumnType("int");
    }
}
```

I want to map them using fluent mapping. Employee table has column 'person_id' which is non-nullable. I tried following:

```
HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Employee)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("person_id"));
```

But it fails with:

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException : One
>   or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> person_id: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property
>   name 'person_id' is already defined.

I need PersonId property on its own, so what I basically want is:

```
HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Employee)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.PersonId); // there is no such method
```

But **there is no such method** here as HasForeignKey

Comment: There is no HasForeignKey method, because for this kind of `HasRequired().WithOptional()` relationship, the optional side (`Employee`) will use its primary key as the foreign key.

Comment: Using your case as an example, this makes sense because there are no `Employee` entities that don't have a corresponding `Person`, so having both `Employee.PersonId` and `Employee.Id` is redundant. If you want `PersonId` to be the foreign key, you can use `HasKey(emp => emp.PersonId)`.

Comment: Once you have multiples of this type of relationship, things fall apart, though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

OK, I figured that out - you should use `WithMany` (yep, not obvious) in order to store foreign key in some property:

```
Property(e => e.PersonId).HasColumnName("person_id");
HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);
```

See [One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) article for details. BTW this will create employee foreign key column for person's table, but there is no other way to have navigation property and foreign key separately.

---

If you need foreign key read-only, you can change PersonId property to:

```
public int PersonId { get { return Person.Id; } }
```

And use your original mapping

```
HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Employee)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("person_id"));
```

Comment: From the article: "As you may have noticed, both associations in the fluent API code has been configured as a many-to-one—not one-to-one, as you might have expected. The reason is simple: Code First (and EF in general) does not natively support one-to-one foreign key associations."

Comment: Ad 1: problem is, I need Person.Employee navigation Property which this solution does not provide
Ad 2: nice hack, but it forces join in case I need PersonId only (without whole Person)
Ad article: I'll look into it later

Comment: This is a dumb way to have to configure this relationship as defeats the point of `.HasRequired().WithOptional()` fluent syntax, EF should just add `.HasForeignKey()` to the above fluent chain or not provide the above chain at all.

Comment: This has been driving my up the wall.  Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @joozek: Have you find a solution to this problem without forcing the join?

Comment: @TomPažourek whoa, dude, It's been some time! If I recall correctly I didn't find satisfying solution and ended up avoiding the need for such mapping

Comment: @joozek: Thanks for answer. I couldn't find a solution anywhere, only people having the same issue. I tried to isolate the problem and posted new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313842/mapping-foreign-key-in-hasoptional-withoptionaldependent-relation-in-entity Hopefully I'll find the answer.

Comment: The design of this EF fluent API is so bad, it would take an incredible amount of effort to make it any more counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a better way to do this:

```
HasKey(e => e.PersonId);

HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Employee);
```

Note that you no longer need the `Employee.Id` property with this approach, as it was superfluous in terms of a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't remember clearly circumstances of my question (it was a few years ago), but I'm certain that I couldn't remove `Employee.Id`, because I was working with legacy db that I didn't own